# Vscode editor indentation errors with python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: vscode editor indentation error]

Why yesterday my vscode is working but today any indentation is regarded as errors?

My vscode just follow the default settings and I'm running simple Python code.

Answer (score 1):

The `...` that is displayed after you entered `for i in range(10)` indicates to you, that the interpreter has noticed that you are not done entering the command yet (it expects the body of the loop to be entered now). If you just hit `Enter`, then you will get the error you have seen.

So what your command should look like is

```
>>>for i in range(10):
...   print(i) # Note that body of for loop has to come in the line preceded with ...
```